# Sublime Text plugin, get line and column from selection

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to get the line and col from a region. So the line and col from the beginning and the end. But I didn't find any function for this in the Sublime Text API.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API to call is `view.rowcol`.

---

To use it on a region in a selection, assume you have a region `r`.

You can use

```
startrow, startcol = view.rowcol(r.a)
endrow, endcol = view.rowcol(r.b)

{
    'start': {'line': startrow, 'col': startcol},
    'end': {'line': endrow, 'col': endcol}
}
```

Note that "start" and "end" have a variety of meanings with regards to selections. You might for instance want to replace `r.a, r.b` with `r.begin(), r.end()`.

Comment: Yeah but the argument is a `point` and `sel()` return a `Region`

Comment: But then the answer depends on what you want to do. If you have a selection of nonzero size, what result do you want? What if the selection is backwards?

Comment: If a selection is nonzero, I would like to have something like that : `{'start' : {'line' : 10, 'col' : 3}, 'end' : {'line' : 15, 'col' : 7}}`. And yeah I guess having a backwards selection can be a problem maybe

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks a lot I didn't know the value return by `region.begins()` was a point.